# Class not found exception while installing jar created using izpack 5.0.10

Tags: izpack

While upgrading `Izpack` 4.x.x version to 5.0.10, I got this

> **"java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.izforge.izpack.panels.path.PathSelectionPanel"**

I have created the installer jar but while installing the .jar, I got the above said error. Is there any solution to overcome this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same error.  It went away when I added either a `TargetPanel` or a `DefaultTargetPanel`.  My original `install.xml` lacked one.

Comment: Good Job, Thank you so much that resolved my error and confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add schema in your XML file in installation tag.
It solved my problem.
**eg.**

```
<izpack:installation version="5.0"
xmlns:izpack="http://izpack.org/schema/installation"
                 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                 xsi:schemaLocation="http://izpack.org/schema/installation http://izpack.org/schema/5.0/izpack-installation-5.0.xsd">

<izpack:installation>
```

Cheers.